# How to get one composite score to represent a MIMIC factor (including both formative variables and reflective indicators)

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, measurement

I have a MIMIC model where the latent variable of interest has both formative causes and reflective indicators (as depicted in the figure).

**My question is:** is there a way to get one composite score to represent the latent factor F1 while keeping most of the measurement structures (that the latent factor has multiple indicators and multiple causes)?

Specifically, can I use PCA to combine the formative measures, and FA to combine the reflective measures, then aggregate those scores to get one composite score? Or would PCA be sufficient to reduce all of the measures? Or something else?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Do you actually have three Y vars, or is that just illustrative?

Comment: I have four formative measures and four reflective measures in the actual case. Would that make any differences?

Comment: Yeah, if you had 3 reflective indicators, then the model is saturated and that means you can treat them separately, because they have no effect on the latent.

Comment: In the actual model, not all of the formative measures were correlated and we fixed one of the loadings to 1. In this case, should we still treat them separately?